# Word frequencies

Tags: java, frequency

I'm writing a Java program that calculates the frequencies of words in an input. The initial integer indicates how many words will follow. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numberWords = scnr.nextInt();
      String[] wordsList = new String[numberWords];
      int i;
      int j;
      int[] frequency = new int[numberWords];
      

      for (i = 0; i < numberWords; ++i) {
         wordsList[i] = scnr.next();
         frequency[i] = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < numberWords; ++j) {
            if (wordsList[i].equals(wordsList[j])) {
               frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1;
            }
         }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < numberWords; ++i) {
         System.out.print(wordsList[i] + " - " + frequency[i]);
         System.out.print("\n");
      }
      
   }
}
```

When I input the following:

```
6 pickle test rick Pickle test pickle
```

This is the output:

```
pickle - 1
test - 1
rick - 1
Pickle - 1
test - 2
pickle - 2
```

However, this is the expected output:

```
pickle - 2
test - 2
rick - 1
Pickle - 1
test - 2
pickle - 2
```

It looks like it's picking up the correct frequencies for later occurrences, but not for the initial occurrences.

Comment: When word `i` is the same as word `j`, you increment `frequency[i]`. What about `frequency[j]`?

Answer (score 2):

For such a scenario you, either use a Map, where you keep the frequency for each word, or you can even do it with a stream and a group by. You don't even need to know the number of words in advance, assuming you simply split them by a space.

With a stream it's basically a oneliner:

```
String input = "pickle test rick Pickle test pickle";
// With a stream:
Map<String, Long> result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s, Collectors.counting()));
```

The map contains:

```
{Pickle=1, test=2, rick=1, pickle=2}
```

If you don't like streams, simply iterate manually over the words, and increment the value of the word (which is used as key in your map).

Comment: Tip: `s->s` can be replaced with `Function.identity()`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Map for this. A map can be used to store a value for a given key. You can use your words as keys and their counts as values. Using a Map makes your code easier to understand, shorter, and less prone to errors. For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int wordCount = s.nextInt();
  
        for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; ++i) {
            String word = s.next();
            int count = frequencies.getOrDefault(word, 0);
            frequencies.put(word, count + 1);
        }
  
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> item : frequencies.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(item.getKey() + ": " + item.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `HashMap` containing frequencies of each word is the most performant approach.

One of the ways to do it is by using method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), that was introduced in the `Map` interface with Java 8. It expects three arguments: a *key*, a *value* to be associated with that *key* (if it was not present in the map) and a *function* that would be evaluated if the already exists, and we need to merge the previous value and a new one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberWords = scanner.nextInt();
    
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberWords; i++) {
        frequencies.merge(scanner.next(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    
    frequencies.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Pickle -> 1
test -> 2
rick -> 1
pickle -> 2
```

In case if you're comfortable with Stream API, you can approach this problem using built-in *collector* [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) (***note*** that we can read the input directly from the stream):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = IntStream.range(0,scanner.nextInt())
        .mapToObj(i -> scanner.next())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            i -> 1,
            Integer::sum
        ));
    
    frequencies.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Pickle -> 1
test -> 2
rick -> 1
pickle -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this instruction:

```
if (wordsList[i].equals(wordsList[j]))
```

`wordsList[j]` is null if j > i. This happens because you scan the words in external for, so in the inner for you don't know the words at indexes > i.

Because of that, when you perform the comparison, the second word results as null for indexes j > i.

Answer (score 0):

I used another string variable I named currWord to hold the values in wordsList[i] and then compared currWord to wordsList[j]. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] userString = new String[20];
        int [] wordFreq = new int[20];
        String currWord;
        int stringLength;
        int i;
        int j;
      
        stringLength = scnr.nextInt();
        userString = new String[stringLength];
        wordFreq = new int[stringLength];
      
        for (i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
            userString[i] = scnr.next();
            wordFreq[i] = 0;
        }
      
        for (i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
            currWord = userString[i];
            for (j = 0; j < stringLength; ++j) {
                if (userString[j].compareTo(currWord) == 0) {
                wordFreq[i] = wordFreq[i] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
         
        for (i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
            System.out.println(userString[i] + " - " + wordFreq[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      // length of the array
      int numWords = scnr.nextInt();

      // array containing the string of words later to be set by the user.
      String[] wordsList = new String[numWords];

      int i;
      int j;

      // array to tally the number of occurrences of a given word.
      int[] numOccur = new int[numWords];
      
      // Use input from user and assign it with values in array.
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
         wordsList[i] = scnr.next();
      }

      // nested for loop. to check matching values in array.
      // if value is found the occurrence array at the same index of the matching string is incremented.  
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
         for (j = 0; j < numWords; ++j) {
            if (wordsList[i].equals(wordsList[j])) {
               numOccur[i]++;
            }
         }
      }

      // this prints the string element and its corresponding value in the occurrences array. 
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
         System.out.println(wordsList[i] + " - " + numOccur[i]);
      }
      
   }
}
```

Comment: You do not want to the loop you are getting the user input from in the same loop you are checking the values. Instead create two sperate loops. Also initializing your frequency array with 0 inside your loop may also cause problems.

Comment: This code snippet appears to read input, tally word occurrences in an array, and display the results. However, it could be improved by adding explanations for better understanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just needed another for loop for i, idk why Java is like this but sometimes to make something happen properly you have to have the same for loop typed out like 30 times :/ Below is your code just with the extra for loop added and it prints properly now. (I organized my code a little differently so let me know if you have any questions.)

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      /* Type your code here. */

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
      
      String[] word = new String[20];
      int[] frequency = new int[20];
      int numWords; 
      int i; 
      int j; 
      
      numWords = scnr.nextInt();
      
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
         word[i] = scnr.next();
         frequency[i] = 0;
      }                                 // I ended the previous for loop to start the next one
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {      // second for loop is here
         for (j = 0; j < numWords; ++j) {
            if (word[i].equals(word[j])) {
               ++frequency[i];
            }
         }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
         System.out.println(word[i] + " " + "-" + " " + frequency[i]);
      }
   }
}
```